# How to eliminate displaying float values from WinRT XAML Toolkit chart if it is bound to integers?

Tags: windows-8, charts, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

[image]

I am using line chart from WinRT XAML Toolkit. Now my `IndependentValueBinding` is done from integer values from 1 to 5, but when it is displayed, it also shows floating values like 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, etc....

So how can I display only 1, 2, 3, 4 & 5 on the X axis.

Comment: I'll be interested to know the solution too, so I can add a sample. :)

Comment: See my answer with update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**

If you add `IndependentAxis`, then you will face clipping issue of data points, so here's solution for that.

[How to set axis margin in WinRT XAML Toolkit line chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566488/how-to-set-axis-margin-in-winrt-xaml-toolkit-line-chart)

---

Finally I added this, and it worked.

```
((LineSeries)MyChart.Series[0]).IndependentAxis = new LinearAxis
                                                  {
                                                      Minimum = 1,
                                                      Maximum = 5,
                                                      Orientation = AxisOrientation.X,
                                                      Interval = 1
                                                  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the WinRT XAML Toolkit, but with Telerik RadChart I have just solved the same issue by setting a property called `MajorStep` (which controls the value distance between the major tick lines of the axis) to a suitable integer value. Maybe WinRT XAML Toolkit has a similar property?