# How to set axis margin in WinRT XAML Toolkit line chart?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, charts, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml-toolkit

**Answer**

Finally I solved my answer with this.

```
((LineSeries)MyChart.Series[0]).IndependentAxis = new LinearAxis
                                                  {
                                                      Minimum = 1,
                                                      Maximum = 5,
                                                      Orientation = AxisOrientation.X,
                                                      Interval = 1,
                                                      Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0)
                                                  };

((LineSeries)MyChart.Series[0]).Clip = null;
((LineSeries)MyChart.Series[0]).Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0);
```

---

I am drawing line chart with help of [WinRT XAML Toolkit](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/). I am setting X axis manually, but when I set I am getting wierd start & end point. I tried to set margin and padding but it's not working. Will you please suggest me how can I do that ?

```
((LineSeries)MyChart.Series[0]).IndependentAxis = new LinearAxis
                                                  {
                                                      Minimum = 1,
                                                      Maximum = 5,
                                                      Orientation = AxisOrientation.X,
                                                      Interval = 1,
                                                      //Margin = .... Not working
                                                      //Padding = .... Not working
                                                  };
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a visual tree debugger to walk up the visual tree from these data points to see where the Clip property is set. In fact I just did that on the samples project and it is set on the LineSeries. See if it's set as part of its XAML template or if it is done in C# and remove it there. Also you could change the Minimum/Maximum values on your X axis to make more space. I'll add cleaning this all up to my TODO list.