# How to scale axes of winrt toolkit charts?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

"I'm using the charts coming with the Winrt Xaml Toolkit. Despite some (xaml) errors most charts are displayed well. But the sacling of the axes isn't working. As soons as I try to define a min, max or interval value I get the following errror:

Failed to create a 'Windows.Foundation.IReference`1' from the text '1'

```
<charting:Chart x:Name="GradePointAverage" Title="Line Chart" Width="650" Height="650">
    <charting:Chart.Axes>
        <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="X" Title="x axis" Interval="1" Minimum="1" Maximum="6"    />
        <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Title="y axis"  ShowGridLines="True" />
    </charting:Chart.Axes>
    <charting:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding HalfYear}"
                            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Average}" IsSelectionEnabled="True" AnimationSequence="FirstToLast" TransitionDuration="0:0:5"   />
</charting:Chart>
```

Besides all charts are marked as "A value of type [chart type] cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'collection`1'". I installed the toolkit through nuget and have already tried reinstalling.

Answer (score 1):

I have had various problems too with setting the Minimum, Maximum and interval in xaml. But was able to fix it by doing it in C# instead.
Something like this should probably work: (based of this: [How to set axis margin in WinRT XAML Toolkit line chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566488/how-to-set-axis-margin-in-winrt-xaml-toolkit-line-chart))

```
((LineSeries)GradePointAverage.Series[0]).IndependentAxis = new LinearAxis
                                              {
                                                  Minimum = 1,
                                                  Maximum = 6,
                                                  Orientation = AxisOrientation.X,
                                                  Interval = 1
                                              };

((LineSeries)GradePointAverage.Series[0]).DependentRangeAxis = new LinearAxis
                                                  {
                                                      Orientation = AxisOrientation.Y,
                                                      ShowGridLines = true
                                                  };
```